# Augment the tree data structure for disjoint sets to implement the PRINT operation

Tags: algorithms, trees, linked-lists, disjoint-sets

Consider the following new operation for disjoint sets
PRINT(x): print every element in S_x the set containing x

**One Approach that I found but couldn't figure out completely :** 
In addition to tree we store a linked list. And each node in the tree in addition to the element
the tree nodes also stores the pointer to element in  the linked list.

UNION(x,y) : We union the x and y as usual. But we join the linked list for x and y 
So here I could simply point the tail of one list to the head of another.

Print(x) : we obtain the s=FIND-SET(x) and print all the elements of the linked list pointed to 
by s. This will print all the elements.
Now for this to work in the UNION to merge the linked list has to be done in a proper way so that
the root of the tree always point to the beginning of the list. 
This can be done like when I merge Tree2 into Tree1 that is point the root of Tree1 to root of 
Tree2 then I point the tail of Tree2 list to head of Tree1 list. In the way the merged list 
will start with the root node of the tree (or the extra element stored in the root of tree)

Will this approach work or there are some flaws in this ?

**Confusion points :**

1. MAKE-SET(x) It's always mentioned that it takes O(1) time. As we have to create a single node 
   But what if the element x is already there. Then we don't create the node we have to first 
   execute FIND-SET(x) and see if it returns anything and then execute MAKE-SET(x).

Comment: What is exactly your confusion point? and what does it have to do with the rest of the question? (i.e., the Print operation). Your approach of the linked list will work in the sense that: if you keep a linked list for each set, then of course you can print it whenever you want. If you have $L_1$, the list corresponding to a set $S_1$, and $L_2$ corresponding to $S_2$,  then when merging $S_1$ and $S_2$,  simply joining their linked lists as $L_1 \to L_2$ gives you a linked list of the union. Are you worried about the complexity? the implementation?

Comment: 1) Whether this approach of merging linked list works and with required complexity. I am somewhat unconfident about the approach. But as you mentioned this approach seems coorect.

Comment: 2) The confusion point

Comment: For maintaining the linked-list so that Print is O(S_x). We need to store the head and tail pointer of the list in the tree node. So that will be required to merge the list while doing Union. So here I am storing two extra data in the tree node. Is it possible to do it using just one additional attribute to the tree node

Comment: Why do you want to use one attribute per tree node? You can use constantly many without asymptotically affecting neither the time nor the space complexity

Comment: As @Steven says, it is not clear what exactly is that you want. You already know that Print can be done optimally (proportional to number of things to print). Now the question seems to be about whether there is a way to do something and saving a constant amount of extra space per node... Also your confusion point is not related to Print in any way. I recommend making 1 single question, and making clear what exactly would satisfy you as answer.

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, please create a new post, do not edit an old post. Also, programming question are not in the scope of this community.